# Inserir Select como parâmetro de uma procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

Tenho uma procedure em mysql que recebe alguns parâmetros, gostaria de saber como faço para passar como parâmetro uma consulta.

Ex.: `CALL sp_DisciplinaSave(SELECT ec.nome, ec.codigo, '' as sEmenta,'' as sCompetencias,'' as sConteudo,'' as sMetodologia,'' as sBibliografiaBasica,'' as sBibliografiaComplementar FROM db_ead.ac_cursos AS ec)`

A procedure recebe 8 parâmetros e o select retorna 8 colunas, isso é possível? Qual a sintaxe certa?

Comment: Já avaliou a utilização dos comandos PREPARE / EXECUTE?

Comment: Ainda não, como seria?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html